# Reading values from file and assigning it to variable in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to read the file which contains the value of some variables which are used in my batch script. 
I have created a property file with format

```
key=key_value
key=key_value
```

Now, I want to set environment variable's name as key and its value as key_value
How can I assign?

I have read the file but cannot separate the string "key=key_value" into two strings.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the FOR command you can turn your key/value file from this

```
KEY1=value
KEY2=value
```

into this

```
SET KEY1=value
SET KEY2=value
```

which you can then invoke as a batch file to set all of the keys as environment variables.
this only works if all of the keys are unique, but from your question it sounds like they are.

save this as a batch file

```
@echo off
echo rem generated from keyvalue.txt > keyvalue.bat
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (keyvalue.txt) do @echo set %%I >> keyvalue.bat

call keyvalue.bat
```

This .bat code assumes that your key/value file is keyvalue.txt and that there are no lines other than blank lines or key=value pairs.

Comment: Just to be picky, you don't need a separate batch file: 

for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (keyvalue.txt) do set %%I 

will work